# RxJava ignore onNext

Tags: java, rx-java, reactive-programming, rx-android, reactivex

I'm calling a url with Retrofit, and I don't care about the result. Is there anyway to ignore the onNext method?

Currently I'm using:

```
getRetrofit().create(UserAPI.class)
        .doSomething(a, b)
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
        .subscribe(t -> {}, Handler::handlerError);
```

As you can see, `t -> {}` do nothing, and I want to reduce it like:

```
getRetrofit().create(UserAPI.class)
            .doSomething(a, b)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
            .subscribe(null, Handler::handlerError);
```

but get the error

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: onNext can not be null
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of `Observable` you can return [Completable](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/Completable.html) from your `Retrofit` interface. It serves exactly same purpose you need.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a way to avoid the `onNext()` implementation when subscribing to an observable if you want to have error handling as well. Alternatively you can create an `Observer` and reuse it in your `subscribe` calls, but you still need to implement the `onNext()` behaviour.

Example:

```
Observer errorObserver = Observers.create(t -> {}, Handler::handleError);

getRetrofit().create(UserAPI.class)
            .doSomething(a, b)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
            .subscribe(errorObserver);
```